# how to show this text in my login page kart******* in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

In my app I have a textfield, in that text field I want to show the text like this `Kart***********`.

**For Example:**
How can I show this mail `Karthik@yopmail.com` to `Kart***********`.

I am storing text in one string like

```
   NSString * loginEmail = @"Karthik@yopmail.com";
   loginEmail = [loginEmail substringToIndex:3];
   NSString *hideMail = [loginEmail substringFromIndex:4];
   [hideMail setSecureTextEntry:YES];
```

I want to change the email text to `Kart********` in my textfield 
Any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString * email = @"Karthik@yopmail.com";
NSString * hiddenMail = [email substringToIndex:4];

NSInteger count = email.length - 4;

for (NSInteger i =0 ; i<count; i++) {
    hiddenMail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@*",hiddenMail];
}

NSLog(@"hidden : %@",hiddenMail);
```

Comment: thanq so much @caglar you saved my life.

Comment: @ananthkumar please accept the answer, if it helps you, thanks